# How to query graphql appsync only that nested data which is non-empty array

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql, backend

I am new to graphql and the problem is I want to fetch only those data which contains image if image is not present then it should not be there in the output list.

```
query MyQuery {
  searchRulers
    items {
      approved
      biography
      createdAt
      fullName
      updatedAt
      location
      keywords
      likedByViewer
      id
      posts {
        items {
          image {
            bucket
            key
            region
            visibility
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I am getting this output

```
{
  "data": {
    "searchRulers": {
      "items": [
        {
          "approved": null,
          "biography": null,
          "createdAt": "2023-03-24T07:21:05.893Z",
          "fullName": "jj kk",
          "updatedAt": "2023-03-24T07:21:05.893Z",
          "location": null,
          "keywords": null,
          "likedByViewer": false,
          "id": "hashid1",
          "posts": {
            "items": [
              {
                "image": {
                  "bucket": "ffjdifgdjsifgdsikgfdkilgnjldsngdfnkdfgdnf",
                  "key": "4f63-af3d-d31aca216c75d.jpeg",
                  "region": "somewhere",
                  "visibility": "public"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "approved": null,
          "biography": null,
          "createdAt": "2023-04-20T09:12:23.531Z",
          "fullName": "nayara cook",
          "updatedAt": "2023-04-20T09:12:23.531Z",
          "location": null,
          "keywords": null,
          "likedByViewer": false,
          "id": "hashid2",
          "posts": {
            "items": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And I am expecting this output where item hashid2 should not be present in the output.

```
{
  "data": {
    "searchRulers": {
      "items": [
        {
          "approved": null,
          "biography": null,
          "createdAt": "2023-03-24T07:21:05.893Z",
          "fullName": "jj kk",
          "updatedAt": "2023-03-24T07:21:05.893Z",
          "location": null,
          "keywords": null,
          "likedByViewer": false,
          "id": "hashid1",
          "posts": {
            "items": [
              {
                "image": {
                  "bucket": "ffjdifgdjsifgdsikgfdkilgnjldsngdfnkdfgdnf",
                  "key": "4f63-af3d-d31aca216c75d.jpeg",
                  "region": "somewhere",
                  "visibility": "public"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to add filter like this   { posts: { items: { size: { gt: 0 } } } }
but size field is not a standard GraphQL field or operator.

Comment: GraphQL, despite its name, is **not** a query language; it does not have built-in operators for filtering or sorting. Your GraphQL server defines what is possible via its *schema*. If you control your server then you can implement whatever filters and sorts you want in your *resolvers*. OTOH if you don't then you are at the mercy of the server author.

Comment: Thanks @MichelFloyd,I'll try to handle this by resolver.